# Question Ban Message

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, post-ban

I was browsing the Help Center when I came across this page. It gives an example of a message someone would see when question banned:

> We are no longer accepting questions from this account. See [the Help Center](/help/question-bans) to learn more.

Later in the page I see the detail:

> The only way to end a posting block is to positively contribute to the site; automatic bans never expire or "time out".

It seems to me that the message should tell the user about that so they don't just leave and come back a month later expecting it to be gone. My suggestion would be to make it say:

> We are no longer accepting questions from this account. This ban will not expire automatically. See [the Help Center](/help/question-bans) to learn more and find out how to get it lifted.

Comment: `We are no longer accepting questions from this account. This ban will never expire.` I've never been question banned, but if this ever greeted me I would stop reading right there, leave and never come back.

Comment: Then perhaps "This ban will not automatically expire."?

Comment: @TinyGiant though, given what it takes to *enter* that ban, may not be such a bad thing...

Comment: While your idea is sound, your suggestion would backfire a bit. Perhaps instead: `We are no longer accepting questions from this account. This ban does not time out and can only be lifted by positive actions from you.` And then the help center link. Then they know it doesn't time out, but it's more obvious that it can be lifted.

Comment: @Kendra Do you like what I edited it to?

Comment: Better. I think there's still some tweaking that could be done, but I'm not sure of specifics to suggest. After all, we don't want to make it too wordy, but we want to get the point across.

Comment: Also, kudos for actually _reading_ the help center. :) A lot of new or low rep users don't.

Comment: @Kendra I think that this would immediately evoke the question `What constitutes a positive action?` so maybe that part would need to be rephrased

Comment: @TinyGiant Which would be explained in the following link. I like Virtual's current suggestion better than my own, honestly.

Comment: Why do you have this ban will never expire or time out? Ban means forever and ever, so that part is a little unnecessary.

Comment: This is already expressed in two words: "no longer". I don't see why we need to add another sentence that says the exact same thing.

Comment: @BoltClock "No longer" says "used to but currently do not". It says nothing about the future.

Comment: Fair enough. I still think it's unnecessary to spell it out though, for the reason given by @Tiny Giant. But then again, I've seen users trying to post at least 3 years after they were last blocked, to no avail.

Comment: "Users don't read" is a truism for sure... However, few users who don't read will exit the ban no matter how cleverly we phrase this message.

Comment: Unrelated but why does the ban page say “You have reached your question limit”? To me that suggests something along the lines of “You have exhausted your limit of  5 questions a week.” Do any of you agree?

Comment: Question, does the ban apply to commenting and voting on others questions?

Comment: @Rishav Kundu: There are in fact temporary rolling rate limits for asking questions, and users who have been rate limited will see that same message. I agree that lumping the indefinite ban message under the same heading can seem a bit confusing at first, but I can see why they are associated.

Comment: @Evan Carslake: No, it only applies to posting questions or answers. Commenting and voting can only be curtailed by an account suspension.

Comment: @BoltClock I am seeing that message but I don’t think I have been rate limited. Also the help centre link points to the low-quality question page.

Comment: @BoltClock http://imgur.com/73tuVxU

Comment: @Rishav Kundu: That's why I said having the "you have been banned" message under the same heading can seem confusing.

Comment: @BoltClock are you sure I have been time-banned? I haven’t posted too many questions lately. Many of them have been down voted though.

Comment: @RishavKundu: Until you gain slightly more rep you are lumped in with all the other users on the same IP for which the same holds. Not sure about the limit just now...

Comment: The key thing I think should be addressed regarding this is what I posted for my answer. How many tries are you willing to give someone before they can't earn them back?

Comment: I disagree. People can always change, and since it's an automatic ban, there's no stress on the community for them to keep trying.

Comment: @virtualdxs I think it should be looked at. If you gave one user over 100 tries and he still can't get it right you have to cut your loses. Some people can't change or won't change. If they keep asking bad question it causes the website to lose creditability and people will stop using it as a reliable answer to their issues. I always look at stackoverflow before any other programming websites. If the data becomes to bad then I may not trust any answer as a reliable answer.

Comment: They *CAN'T* ask more bad questions. They're question-banned until they fix what they have.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I like the new wording in principle, but I think that the passive voice is entirely inappropriate for "get it lifted".  This suggests that someone else will take action to lift the ban, if they just complain enough to the right party, which isn't true.

Therefore, I suggest that the final sentence be

> See [the Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) to learn more and find out how to earn back privileges you've lost.

This places the emphasis on the (ab)user -- they lost the privileges through their own actions, and they need to actively work to get them back.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it fits the goal best. The reason I disagree with [DeadChex's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297378/3042952) is because I believe that there are those who could do better on SE if they understand how it works, so this is better since it does not put an additional strain on the community, and may very well improve it.

Answer (score 8):

I think the ban message as-is is okay. The user should be able to realize they're doing something wrong before they get banned: their questions are downvoted a lot, the community is telling them what's wrong (through comments or the close notice), and they have to continually do it.

Because they already have been given information about how to improve, and didn't act on it, if they want to come back they should at least show some effort and click the Help Center link which goes to an article that's fairly straight to the point.

**tldr**: A ban is punishment for not taking the advice already offered, correcting and taking it should be up to the user now; the community has already tried.